# Trying to make a auction system in discord py, but it doesn't work after it prints out the auctioned item. (discord bot)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def auction(ctx):
    global footballers
    global round_done
    global last_bid
    global last_bidder
    global is_auction_on

    class Player:
        team_count = 0

        def __init__(self, budget, team_name):
            self.budget = budget
            self.team_name = team_name
            Player.team_count += 1

        def money_spent(self, sp):
            self.budget = self.budget - sp

    auctioned_players = 0
    last_bidder = ""
    last_bid = 0
    player_ids = []
    last_bidder_id = 0
    last_message_timestamp = 0.00
    await ctx.send("How many people will be playing?")
    player_count = 0
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=3):
        if message.author == bot.user:
            continue
        if not message.content.isdigit():
            continue
        player_count = int(message.content)
        break
    if player_count != 0:
        await ctx.send("Enter your team names")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        async for message in ctx.channel.history(limit=player_count):
            message.author = Player(100000, message.content)
            player_ids.append(message.author)
        if Player.team_count != 0:
            await ctx.send("Starting the auction.")
            while auctioned_players < player_count * 11 + player_count * 2:
                is_auction_on = True
                auctioned_player = random.choice(footballers)
                await ctx.send(auctioned_player)
                async for a in ctx.channel.history(limit=1):
                    if a.author == bot.user:
                        last_message = a
                auctioned_players += 1
                countdown = 0.0
                message_count = 0
                while countdown < 5 + message_count:
                    async for b in ctx.channel.history(limit=10, after=last_message):
                        if not b.content.isdigit():
                            continue
                        if b.author == bot.user:
                            continue
                        if int(b.content) < last_bid:
                            continue
                        last_bid = int(b.content)
                        last_bidder = str(message.author)
                        last_message = b
                        message_count += 1
                        await asyncio.sleep(1)
                        countdown += 1
                if last_bid > 0:
                    for a in player_ids:
                        if a == last_bidder:
                            last_bidder_id = player_ids.index(a)
                    player_ids[last_bidder_id].money_spent(last_bid)
                    await ctx.send(
                        f"Auction ended. {player_ids[last_bidder_id].team_name} bought {auctioned_player} for {last_bid}")
                    last_bid = 0
                    last_bidder = ""
                    is_auction_on = False
```

-!auction

+How many people will be playing?

-1

+Enter your team names

-lol

+Starting the auction.

Manuel Ugarte

Christian Pulisic

etc...

This is how it always goes.

It should-after the countdown ends- print out the value bidded and the winner, which worked before. But after I added the countdown system it started to don't even reach that far into the code, I saw that from the debugs. There are no errors given out while running or beforehand in my code, AI can't solve it either. I have imported the correct modules as well. I'm going crazy about this, I even tried the onmessage function but that produced the exact same outcome.

Thx in advance